# Measuring and modelling mass-loss from confined gas phase due to diffusion

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, diffusion

I am trying to model substance losses from an enclosed higher-concentration gas phase (uncompressed CO2-enriched air) that circulates through an arrangement of containers and tubes.

[image: Experiment sketch]

My intention is to derive a value that allows me to compute (molecular) flow rates from the enclosed space ("How many molecules escape per hour?"). The reason I need this is that I ultimately need to consider those losses in another computation.

There are various points through which I assume losses could occur: The couplings of the tubes to the containers are not perfect, the tubes themselves are made from silicone and might also leak, and there are other perforations (such as the joint where the sensor enters the enclosed space) might also be leaky.

I initially tried starting from the diffusive transport term

$$
j^*_A = -D_{AB} \frac{dc}{dX}
$$

... but with the complex set-up I had, gave up on that quickly. Also, I dont really need to model the geometry and compute losses; I have measured curves and want a "robust" way to compute a concentration-dependant flow rate from those, and this did not seem like a good way to go.

My second attempt was by using a balance of the enclosed space. Skipping a bit of theory, I'd expect a solution in the form of

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}\label{eq1}
c(t)= c_o \cdot e^{-kt}
\end{equation}

At first we would need to compute the unknowns $c_0$ and $k$ from  measurements of $ c(t) $.
The easiest way to do so should be by computing the logarithm of the measurements, then using linear regression to fit a line as shown in \eqref{eq2}

\begin{equation}
\tag{2}\label{eq2}
c^*(t) = mt + b
\end{equation}

Then we compute the log of the exponential function in \eqref{eq1}

\begin{equation}
\tag{3}\label{eq3}
log(c) = log(c_0) -kt
\end{equation}

and compare coeffiencts of $\eqref{eq2}$ and $\eqref{eq3}$, yielding
$$ log(c_o) = b \Rightarrow c_0 = e^b $$
$$ k = m $$

As this describes a time-dependant concentration it is not so great for comparisons. I'd like to have a flow rate (molecular, volumetric or mass-based all seem fine) depending on the current concentration in the enclosed space.

A general connection between the molecular count, the concentration and the Volume is given by \eqref{eq4}

\begin{equation}
\tag{4}\label{eq4}
n = c \cdot V
\end{equation}

We can rewrite \eqref{eq1} using \eqref{eq4} to obtain a time-dependant molecular count $n(t)$ in \eqref{eq5}.

\begin{equation}
\tag{5}\label{eq5}
n(t) = V c_0 e^{-kt} 
\end{equation}

To obtain a flow *rate*, we derive $n(t)$ from \eqref{eq5}

\begin{equation}
\tag{6}\label{eq6}
\frac{dn(t)}{dt} = \dot{n}(t) = - V c_0 k e^{-kt}
\end{equation}

To eliminate the dependency on $t$, we rearrange the first equation as shown in \eqref{eq7}. I think this can be done since the losses are very small compared to the total volume. Approximately 1/10000th per hour.

\begin{equation}
\tag{7}\label{eq7}
c(t)= c_o \cdot e^{-kt} \Rightarrow t = -\frac{ln(c(t))-ln(c_o)}{k} 
\end{equation}

Plugging \eqref{eq7} into \eqref{eq6} yields

\begin{equation}
\tag{8}\label{eq8}
\dot{n}(c(t)) = -V \cdot c_0 \cdot k \cdot e^{k \cdot \frac{ln(c(t)) - ln(c_o)}{k}} = -V \cdot c(t) \cdot k
\end{equation}

Dropping the time dependency of the concentration results in the desired expression in \eqref{eq9}

\begin{equation}
\tag{9}\label{eq9}
\dot{n}(c) = -V \cdot c \cdot k
\end{equation}

The last step is bothering me, because formally, the concentration still carries its time-dependency, even though I am sure that I've removed all dependencies on $t$.
Is it formally acceptable just to drop $(t)$ in this case, to conclude with the result shown in \eqref{eq9}?

Is the calculation generally sound?

Comment: Hi. Your opening paragraph is very unclear, at least to a simpleton like me. A diagram might help. You mention 'the diffusion equations' but what you cite aren't generally recognised diffusion equations, like Fick's 2nd Law. You may be starting off on the wrong foot, in which case success may not be forthcoming.

Comment: I edited a bit, hopefully it is clear now?

Comment: Yes, the diagram is useful, ta.